# How can I manage an AD group through SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, email, active-directory, exchange

I have a hosted SharePoint and Exchange environment and want to manage email distribution list memberships through SharePoint. Assuming I have some universal security group in AD which is mail-enabled in Exchange, how can I manage the group's membership through SharePoint? Can I sync group members of a SharePoint group to an AD group?

Comment: Do you have NINTEX at all? I believe there are some workflow actions that would assist you

Comment: If it's mail enabled, it can be managed in Outlook.